# GridX showing same data for every row

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo.gridx

I thought I'd put this out there for someone else who might be running into the same thing.  I had a situation where I was loading data into the store of the grid but yet every row was showing the same exact information (and the data in the store was different).  Come to find out, YOU MUST specify the idProperty in your store (in my case a Memory store) in order for the rows to render correctly.

```
var myStore = new Memory({data:[{customerId:'abcd', customerName:'Customer ABC'}, {customerId:'defg', customerName:'Other Customer'}], idProperty:'customerId'`});
```

If you don't put that idProperty in there, you'll get duplicated data.

Comment: Please update the post so the question is a question and then post the solution as an answer. This is perfectly fine - sharing knowledge Q&a-style. But posting the "question" and solution in the same are is not.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with JsonRest store

> new JsonRest({ target: '/rest_url/'**, idProperty: '_id'** })